# A single word for first and last thing?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a specific word that means something that was always there, as in the first thing to be created and the last thing to cease to exist? Like the "Alpha and Omega" concept but in one single word?
As in, what would be called the very first atom to come into existence on this universe if that was the very same atom that will be the last to decay when this universe ceases to exist.

Comment: It would be better if you add an example sentence to your question, as mandated by the [tag:single-word-requests] tag

Comment: The 'Alpha and Omega concept' as used in the Bible certainly doesn't mean 'first thing created ...' but 'pre-existant ...'.

Comment: The phrase "alpha and omega", just like "A to Z", is today often (universally?) used to simply mean "the first and last".  The "real" subtle meaning from biblical English, is rarely used.  EdwinA - you're too clever for your own good as usual  :)

Comment: Thank you, people. I'm gonna try to clarify this. Is there any word, in the english vocabulary, that means the very first thing of something, which is also the very last thing of that same something? Like a word for the very first drop of water to go in a bottle, which is also the very last drop to leave the bottle.

Answer (score 1):

Consider *eternal*. Something that is eternal has always and will ever be. Therefore it must have been first and will of necessity be last. Of course, given eternality, beginning and end don't really have any meaning.

If you're dealing with processes, you might take a page from programming and refer to the *process container* which starts before anything inside it does and finishes after all its contents do.

Comment: Well, you're on the right direction. Take the _process container_ concept and aply it to the entire existence.

Comment: Well, you're on the right direction. I'm trying to find a word for something like the _process container_ concept, but in a larger scale. Something like: is there a word for the process container of the universe?

Answer (score 1):

Boundary/boundaries, border(s)?

Took a bit of abstract thinking - (imposed) boundaries and borders either for the purpose of just existing, or breaking/crossing them, are always present.
"Space: The final frontier"?

Extremes, endpoints, bookends don't carry the same implicit need/intent of breakableness(wouldn't use fragile in this case).

In all honesty, i reckon there's naught a most expressive, specific word for what you seek - correct me if I'm wrong.